# Space before caption

Tags: libreoffice, caption

I need to set space before caption of figure in LibreOffice. How can I do that? I insert caption from Insert->Caption in menu.[image]
Space marked red on picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on the image, go to the "wrap" tab, and add space to the bottom  of the image.

Here's a gif showing these steps in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Format - Styles (F11) and there you can change the formatting for Captions-Illustration.

Comment: Yes, but when I change space before paragraph, the space changes before figure, not before caption!

Comment: And if you adjust the space after the paragraph it doesn't do anything at all. Grrrr!

Comment: Space before paragraph for the Caption->Illustration style should really change the space between image and caption. I think this should be reported as a bug.